# Error converting string to type - Newtonsoft JSON deserialize

Tags: c#, json, json.net, type-conversion

I have a SQL parameter which returns a message if the insert was successful or not.

```
SqlParameter positivePar = new SqlParameter("@jsonGoodData", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
positivePar.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(positivePar);
```

I convert that SQL parameter to a string

```
cmdPositive = cmd.Parameters["@jsonGoodData"].Value.ToString();
```

and I serialize it like so because later on I want to populate a model with the json

```
string jsonPositive = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cmdPositive, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

I am trying to deserialize the json and send it to the model like so

```
List<TableNotificationModel> posJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableNotificationModel>>(jsonPositive);
```

but I get an error:

> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel].

This is the model

```
public class TableNotificationModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("OPERATOR_OBJECTID")]
        public int OPERATOR_OBJECTID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SETTLEMENT_OBJECTID")]
        public string SETTLEMENT_CODE { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TECHNOLOGY_OBJECTID")]
        public string TECHNOLOGY_CODE { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("UPLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_OBJECTID")]
        public string UPLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_OBJECTID")]
        public string DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DATA_CATEGORY_QOS_OBJECTID")]
        public string DATA_CATEGORY_QOS_CODE { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SHAPE")]
        public string SHAPE { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("messageOut")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the value of cmdPositive from the debugger
[image]
and the value of cmdNegative, since only cmdNegative has the error message why the insert failed.
[image]

Should I perhaps not return the SQL parameter as a string? I also tried changing the jsonPositive as a model but it throws an error. Any advice for the intern on how to proceed?

Comment: Show us the model you have and a sample JSON producing the error

Comment: Purpose of serializing is to convert an object to a string and when you already have a string, it will serialize it to an escaped string. When you deserialize that escaped string, you will always get back a string (not a list of object). Do show what that json is supposed to look like that you are trying to deserialize... also, use debugger to see what you have as values that you are serializing and deserializing.

Comment: What is the value of `cmdPositive` (from the debugger)? Also `jsonPositive`. _I strongly suspect you don't need `jsonPositive` at all - and can just use `cmdPositive`._

Comment: I added more info about the model and the JSON @zaitsman :)

Comment: I updated my question with the info you requested @mjwills :)

Comment: You are missing how you get `jsonPositive` you only show how you get `cmdPositive` those are not the same

Comment: Does changing`string jsonPositive = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cmdPositive, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);` to `string jsonPositive = cmdPositive;` fix it?

Comment: I actually used cmdPositive, like so:
`List<TableNotificationModel> posJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableNotificationModel>>(cmdPositive);` 
so can you please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it correct? @mjwills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your use of:

```
string jsonPositive = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cmdPositive, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

This code is unnecessary since `cmdPositive` is not an object that needs to be serialised to JSON - it is *already* JSON.

So, instead:

```
string jsonPositive = cmdPositive;
```

is sufficient (or remove `jsonPositive` altogether and use `cmdPositive` instead).